# Why is my OpenGL program using matrix rotations displaying nothing?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I can't find how to create the view matrix with yaw, pitch and roll. I'm working with LWJGL and have a rotate function available.

```
    viewMatrix.setZero();
    viewMatrix.rotate(pitch, new Vector3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    viewMatrix.rotate(yaw, new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    viewMatrix.rotate(roll, new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    viewMatrix.m33 = 1.0f;
    viewMatrix.translate(position);
```

I am doing something fundamentally wrong, and I hate the fact that I can't fix it do to the lack of documentation (or my lack of google skills).

I do not transpose the matrix.

As a note, position is a zero vector and I do not see anything on the screen (when view matrix is zero I do).

Added: I am trying to reach the equivalent of the following:

```
    GL11.glRotatef(pitch, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glRotatef(yaw, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glRotatef(roll, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, position.z);
```

Comment: The reason you don't see anything on the screen isn't necessarily related to wrong rotation algorithm (which looks ok). Does the `.setZero()` set the matrix to *all zeros*, or to *identity* matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `viewMatrix.setIdentity()` instead of `viewMatrix.setZero()` to initially set the matrix to a unit matrix, instead of zeroing the matrix.

Comment: Care to explain why this results in nothing being drawn?

Comment: Little bit rusty on the topic, but if I'm not mistaken: If you perform operations against a zeroed matrix, you'll just get a zeroed matrix back as anything multiplied by zero, equals zero.

If you perform operations against the identity matrix, you'll be able to get non-zero numbers back as a matrix multiplied by the identity matrix returns the initial matrix.

Answer (score 0):

compounding rotations like that is the wrong way to go about it, try this: http://tutorialrandom.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-rotate-in-3d-using-opengl-proper.html

Comment: It would be nice to explain *why* this is bad, except for linking to random tutorial, which isn't a very good quality either. Also, it doesn't actually address the question.